# Which resources gets freed on rebooting the linux server?

Tags: ubuntu, memory-usage

I got this msg `-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device` on server, so when I checked size with this `df -h` command, I got following result

```
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                  487M     0  487M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 100M   12M   88M  12% /run
/dev/xvda1                            7.8G  7.5G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                 496M  4.0K  496M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                 496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/localteams-localteamslv1  9.8G  2.0G  7.3G  21% /local-teams
tmpfs                                 100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1001
```

I also tried to cleat /tmp folder but in that folder only 2 files are there also refered [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380238/how-to-clean-tmp) not happening anything...

That's why, I want to know which resources gets freed on rebooting the server?
So I can use cron job to drill it periodically..

Or what is the solution to do this...because it is not possible to reboot the server each time..

Thank You in advance

**Note:** you can ask more detail as required

Comment: Your root file-system is full. And although your `/tmp` is on your root partition so are many other directories, so if temp data is not the reason you're running out of disk space, you need to find out where else... (the `du` and `ncdu` might help you there.)  -|-

Comment: Figure out where your file space has gone, e.g. `sudo du -ax / | perl -ne '/^\d{5,}/ and print' | sort -rn | tee /dev/shm/root.du-a | less`, look at the biggest files (at the top) and decide whether they can be removed, archived offline, or compressed.

Answer (score 5):

The error `No space left on device` means that your disk is full and you need to free some space by deleting or moving some files from your `/` partition (which is shown as 100% used).

One good location to start looking for large files that can be (re)moved is `/var/log/`.

Rebooting the server does not help in your case.

Answer (score 2):

> which resources gets freed on rebooting the server?

With regards to disk usage that is actually a mildly interesting question:

- Generally rebooting won't do much, it would be a Really Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup> if a reboot would result in data disappearing!
- A reboot will result in freeing up disk space from **already deleted files** that were still held open by running processes (i.e. the ones you get to see with `lsof | grep deleted`). You could achieve the same by terminating the specific processes instead.
- Some distributions run a `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp` clean up script at reboot.
- You'll lose all data from [tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt) and similar file-systems that only exist in-memory

---

Your root file-system is full and it will contain (too much) data in other directories than `/tmp` as well. Check with for instance `du` or `ncdu` where data is consumed to see if you can safely delete some.
Alternatively since this appears to be a VPS, simply add additional space by increasing the disk and file-system.